# Jquery/Angular and html

Tags: jquery, angularjs

when i am using JQuery dataTable in my html page ,ng-model of angularjs is not working and the form that is created by dataTable before embedding angularjs is also get hidden like pagination and searching so how to resolve it?

Comment: Please share your code/workaround so that we can take a look. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do some debugging. That's it. We can help you this much without looking any code.